# How to ensure data is not lost on page refresh using PHP Cookies

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, cookies

I have a dynamic form that I am trying to create which I will save to MySQL database.  What I want to do is to have so many dynamic rows on the page but to save the information typed in the fields to be stored in a PHP SESSION that will keep the data if the page is refreshed etc.

I cannot figure out how to get the data to be stored in PHP SESSIONS, any help would be much appreciated.

```js
//adds extra table rows
var i=$('tr').length;
$(".addmore").on('click',function(){
 
 html = '<tr>';
 html += '<td><input class="case" type="checkbox" /></td>';
 html += '<td><input type="text" name="product[]" id="product_'+i+'" class="fld field_large" value="" /></td>'; 
 html += '<td class="ta_r"><input type="text" name="qty[]" id="qty_'+i+'" class="fld field_small trigger qty" value="" /></td>'; 
 html += '<td class="ta_r"><input type="text" name="price[]" id="price_'+i+'" class="fld field_small trigger price" value="0.00" /></td>'; 
 html += '<td class="ta_r"><input type="text" name="line_total[]"id="line_total_'+i+'" value="0.00" class="fld field_small trigger linetotal" disabled="disabled" /></td>'; 
 html += '</tr>';
 $('table').append(html);
 i++;
});

//to check all checkboxes
$(document).on('change','#check_all',function(){
 $('input[class=case]:checkbox').prop("checked", $(this).is(':checked'));

});




//deletes the selected table rows
$(".delete").on('click', function() {
 $('.case:checkbox:checked').parents("tr").remove();
 $('#check_all').prop("checked", false);    
 update();
});

var calcObject = {
 defaultValue : '0.00',
 subTotal : 0,
 vatRate : 20,
 run : function(obj) {
  obj.live('change keyup blur', function(e) {
   calcObject.subTotal = 0;
   var thisQty = jQuery.find('.qty');
   jQuery.each(thisQty, function() {    
    var thisQty = $(this).val();
    var thisPrice = $(this).closest('tr').find('.price').val();
    if (calcObject.isNumber(thisQty) && calcObject.isNumber(thisPrice)) {
     var thisSubTotal = (parseFloat(thisQty) * parseFloat(thisPrice)).toFixed(2);
     $(this).closest('tr').find('.linetotal').val(thisSubTotal);
     calcObject.subTotal += parseFloat(thisSubTotal);
    } else {
     $(this).closest('tr').find('.linetotal').val(calcObject.defaultValue);
    }
   });
   calcObject.update();
  });
 },
 isNumber : function(numb) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(numb)) && isFinite(numb);
 },
 update : function() {
  if (calcObject.isNumber(calcObject.subTotal) && calcObject.isNumber(calcObject.vatRate)) {
   var thisVat = ( (parseFloat(calcObject.subTotal) / 100) * parseFloat(calcObject.vatRate)).toFixed(2);
   var thisTotal = parseFloat(parseFloat(calcObject.subTotal) + parseFloat(thisVat)).toFixed(2);
   $('#subtotal').val(parseFloat(calcObject.subTotal).toFixed(2));
   $('#vat').val(thisVat);
   $('#total').val(thisTotal);
  }
 }
};

function add() {
    document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML += '<input type="text"><br><br>';
    sessionStorage.inputBoxes = document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML;
}

window.load = function() {
   if (sessionStorage.inputBoxes) {
      document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML = sessionStorage.inputBoxes;
   }
};

$(function() {
 calcObject.run($('.trigger'));
});
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: none;
 list-style: none;
 font-weight: 100;
 color: #333;
}
body {
 font-family: Arial, Verdana, Sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 text-align: center; 
 padding: 20px 0;
}
#wrapper {
 text-align: left;
 width: 800px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.fld {
 padding: 3px;
 border: solid 1px #aaa;
}
th,td {
 text-align:left;
 vertical-align:top;
 border-bottom:dashed 1px #aaa;
 padding:7px 10px;
}
.btn {
 padding: 6px 18px;
 color: #fff;
 background: #222;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.dev {
 height:14px
}
.col_1 {
 width: 1%;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
.col_15{width:65%}
.col_5{width:5%}
.ta_r,th.ta_r,.td.ta_r{text-align:right}
.button-success {
 padding: 8px 18px;
 color: #fff;
 background: #0C3;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.button-danger {
 padding-left:20px;
 padding: 8px 28px;
 color: #fff;
 background: #F00;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.form-inline .form-group{
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 float: right;
}

/** Customs CSS **/

.field_large {
 width:450px;
}

.field_small {
 width:50px;
}
.total {
 width:40%; 
 float:right;
 margin-top:50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/core.css" media="all" type="text/css">

</head>
<body>


<div id="wrapper">

 <h1>Invoice Form</h1>
    
    <div class="dev">&#160;</div>
 
 <form method="post">
 
  <table>
   <tr>
             <th width="2%"><input id="check_all" class="formcontrol" type="checkbox"/></th>
    <th>Product name</th>
    <th class="ten left">Qty</th>
    <th class="ten left">Price</th>
    <th class="ten left">Sub-Total</th>
   </tr>
  
   <tr>
                      <!-- remove input tage below to remove first checkbox -->
             <th width="2%"> <input class="case" type="checkbox"/> </th>
                <input type="text" data-type="productCode" name="itemNo[]" id="itemNo_1" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off">
    <td><input type="text" name="product[]" class="fld field_large" value="" /></td>
    <td class="ta_r"><input type="text" name="qty[]" class="fld field_small trigger qty" value="" /></td>
    <td class="ta_r"><input type="text" name="price[]" class="fld field_small trigger price" value="0.00" /></td>
    <td class="ta_r"><input type="text" name="line_total[]" value="0.00" class="fld field_small linetotal" disabled="disabled" /></td>
   </tr>        

  </table>
        
        <div class="dev">&#160;</div>
        
         <button class="button-success addmore" type="button">+ Add More</button>
            <button class="button-danger delete" type="button">- Delete</button>
 
     <div class="dev">&#160;</div>
        
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="total">
   <tr>
    <th><label for="subtotal">Sub-Total: </label></th>
    <td>
    <input type="text" name="subtotal" id="subtotal" value="0.00" class="fld" disabled="disabled" />
             </td>
   </tr>
         
         <tr>
    <th><label for="vat">Vat: </label></th>
    <td>
    <input type="text" name="vat" id="vat" value="0.00" class="fld" disabled="disabled" />
    </td>
   </tr>
         
         <tr>
    <th><label for="total">Total: </label></th>
    <td>
    <input type="text" name="total" id="total" value="0.00" class="fld" disabled="disabled" />
             </td>
   </tr>
   
   <tr>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    <td><label for="btn" class="sbm"><input type="submit" id="btn" class="btn" value="Add" /></label></td>
   </tr>
         
  </table>
     
 
 </form>

</div>


<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/core.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please don't use session. _so many dynamic rows_ will require **so many bytes** in the session (or cookies, as per the title of this question), which is not recommended. Also, cookies support limited data (~4KB). Keep your session clean and tidy. Consider other methods, like LocalStorage, IndexedDB etc., which will be faster.

Comment: Haven't tried it but i guess if for example you have a dropdown item, you could use a jQuery function which fires everytime the item is changed, that particular time you could store it in a session.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the reply I shall have to re access the situation and try something else.  Maybe each time the add row button is pressed the data is saved to MySQL database using jQuery and Ajax.  I think that approach may be better especially for the calculations. Thank you